# Make Highchart and Highstock Have a Uniform Time X-Axis for Disparate Data Points

Tags: highcharts

I have data scattered all over time. I happen to have a lot of samples for August. Highstock currently adjusts the x-axis to fit the data I do have, but I would like to force it to be uniform, so each month is displayed evenly across the x-axis. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: Reminding myself that I also posted the question here: http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=20327

Comment: Without seeing your code we do not know what options you have set. Can you throw up a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`ordinal: false`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) on your `xAxis` definition.